# How to set timeout as variable in Tavern test?

Tags: python, pytest, tavern

I have two yaml files for my tests, `common.yaml` and `test.yaml`. There are some variables defined in `common.yaml`:

```
name: Common test information
description: Common data used by test cases

variables:
  url: http://localhost:8080/v2
  timeout: 30
```

In the test file:

```
includes:
  - !include common.yaml

stages:
  - name: test
    request:
      url: "{url:s}/test"
      method: GET
      timeout: "{timeout:d}"
    response:
      status_code: 200
```

It uses the `timeout` defined on `common` file. I got this error when I run the test:

```
tavern.util.exceptions.BadSchemaError: 'timeout' must be either a float/int or a 2-tuple of floats/ints - got '{timeout:d}' (type <class 'str'>)
```

It seems that Tavern doesn't recognize the type of `timeout`. I have specify the type is `d` in the end but why it doesn't pick up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use timeout: !int "{timeout:d}"

or timeout: !float "{timeout:f}"

to convert type from string